# Vector Calculus

Tags: calculus

I want to show that given $ax+by=c$ the vector $(a,b)$ is perpendicular to the line determined by the equation.

I was thinking using dot product.

Comment: That is a good idea; it will work. Then, what happened?

Comment: How would you figure out a vector that points in the same direction as the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line $\;ax+by=c\;$ can be given in parametric form as (assuming $\;b\neq 0\;$ to avoid trivialities)

$$\left\{\left(x,-\frac ab x+\frac cb\right)\;;\;x\in\Bbb R\right\}=\left\{\left(0,\frac cb\right)+x\left(1,-\frac ab\right)\right\}$$

The direction vector is, of course, $\;\left(1,-\frac ab\right)\;$ , so the dot product is

$$(a,b)\cdot\left(1,-\frac ab\right)=a-a=0\iff (a,b)\perp\left(1,-\frac ab\right)$$

Comment: Wow, I love this solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One question why does $x$ need to be in $R^2$, should this just be $R$?

Comment: @user96137, that was a typo. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

The gradient of $ax + by = c$ is $\frac{-a}{b}$. The gradient of the vector $(a,b)$ is $b\over a$

$\frac{-a}{b}\cdot\frac{b}{a} = -1$ so they are perpendicular.

Comment: This is a really good answer however the book has not yet talked about things being perpendicular if they are negative reciprocals.

Comment: @user96137, I don't knowwhat book is that, but the reciprocals thing is high school's pretty basic analytic geometry...

Comment: @DonAntonio, it's Lang: Calculus of Several Variables. Yes, I know this is a triviality I just figured since I was in a reading through a section about dot product when this was mentioned, then it could be done that way.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equation of the line as follows:

$$\frac{x}{1}=\frac{y-\frac{c}b}{\frac{-a}b}=t$$ So it has the leading vector $(1,\frac{-a}b)$.

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy. The sun is going down here and is going up there. What a close home we live in.

Comment: @amWhy: Thank for your charming words. Wish you a very good holiday ahead. :-)

Answer (score 0):

All your solutions must treat $b=0$ separately. Here's another way.  Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be two points satisfying $ax+by=c$. We have to show that the dot product of $\overline{P_1P_2}$ and $(a,b)$ equals zero.  But that's trivial, subtracting $ax_1+by_1=c$ and $ax_2+by_2=c$ gives $a(x_1-x_2)+b(y_1-y_2)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The line $ax + by = c$ is a level set of the function $F(x,y) = ax + by$. The gradient of $F$ is $\nabla F = (a,b)$. Level sets are always perpendicular to gradients: If $v$ is tangent to a level set, then it is in the kernel of $dF$, so
$$ \langle \nabla F, v\rangle = dF(v) = 0.$$
Therefore, $(a,b)$ is perpendicular to $ax + by = c$.